# assembly: windows dll not shown for "JMP ESP" instruction

Tags: python, assembly, windows-xp, 32-bit

The instructor and me are using Immunity Debugger to test buffer overflow exploitation.

The echo server is running on a Windows XP machine.
The program works fine for me and the instructor.

Just after opening the exe with Immunity Debugger, a custom python script (in Immunity Debugger PyCommands directory) shows where the "JMP ESP" instruction is used, with the different modules.

On the instructor machine, it says it's used in modules ADVAPI32.dll (3 times), mswsock.dll (2 times), RPCRT4.dll (2 times), ntdll.dll (2 times) and WS2_32.dll (1 time).

But in my case, I just get this : 
RCPRT4.dll (4 times) and ADVAPI32.dll (4 times).

I have no "mswsock.dll" and "WS2_32.DLL" like the instructor.

Because of that the exploit in my case is not working, because the instructor is overwriting the EIP address with the "JMP ESP" address of WS2_32.dll, to then inject the "windows/shell/bind_tcp" payload.

Any idea why "mswsock.dll" and "WS2_32.DLL" is not showing in my case ?

If you wonder, here's the Immunity Debugger PyCommands script :

```
import immlib
DESC="Find Instructions"

def main(args) :

    imm = immlib.Debugger()

    assembledInstruction = imm.assemble(' '.join(args))

    if not assembledInstruction : 
        return "[-] No Instruction Given!"

    addressList = imm.search(assembledInstruction) 

    td = imm.createTable("Instruction Locations", ['Module', 'Base Address', 'Instruction Address', 'Instruction'])

    for address in addressList :

        module = imm.findModule(address)
        if not module:
            imm.log("Address 0x%08X not in any module" %address)
            continue

        instruction = ''

        numArgs = len(' '.join(args).split('\n'))

        for count in range(0, numArgs) :
            instruction += imm.disasmForward(address, nlines=count).getDisasm() + ' '

        td.add(0, [ module[0],
                    str('0x%08X'%module[1]),
                    str('0x%08X'%address),
                    instruction
                    ])

    return "Success"
```

Comment: Terminology nitpick:  it's unlikely that instruction is *used* in any of your DLLs in the normal sense, but the 2 bytes that encode it (or `call esp`?) can be *found* in your DLLs as part of other instructions, or overlapping other instructions, or in non-code that's still mapped into memory.

Comment: I don't fully understand, but interestingly, running the script to find "call esp", I find "WS2_32.DLL" listed !  Its instruction address is slightly different than the one the instructor found with "jmp esp".  I tried the attack with the "call esp" WS2_32.DLL instruction address, but it's not working.

Comment: Could it be because of some Windows XP security feature that I don't find the WS2_32.DLL directly for "JMP ESP"  ?   Maybe I have some security patch in my Windows XP that the instructor doesn't have ?

Comment: My point was that calling functions in those DLLs the normal way will never execute `jmp esp`, I can pretty much guarantee.  But x86 instructions are variable length and unaligned, and you can get different instructions if you start decoding at different places.  You're taking advantage of that by looking for a usable 2-byte sequence that decodes as `jmp esp` that's part of other instructions in compiler-generated machine code for the DLLs.

Comment: Sure, updates are possible.  Compare an md5sum of your files to see if you're looking at the same binaries.

Comment: OK.  And could a security update explains that I find "WS2_32.DLL" by looking "call esp",  instead of by looking "jmp esp" like the instructor ?

Comment: When your professor ran the debugger did he at least allow the echo server to run and set up a socket? Is it possible that the reason you don't see any winsock DLL's is that you haven't allowed the echo server to initialize the socket library (which in turn I believe use to load the DLL). I don't know anything about your debugger, but I'd allow the echo server to start running properly, accept a connection from a remote side and then break with the debugger. By that point the winsock DLL should have been in memory.

Comment: To find the "jmp esp", he does not run the program in the debugger. He simply opens the exe with the debugger, and we see the program is paused. And without running the program, he looks for "jmp esp" and finds ws2_32.dll listed.  I don't.

Comment: I'm curious though, in your case if you allow the program to run and then break itno it is the DLL in question listed? Depending on how the target program is made the loading of a DLL can be deferred beyond startup (process creation). Its also possible that on your profs computer that some other process that has provided a hook that happens to load the winsock DLL into every process when loaded into memory(maybe something like VNC, wireshark etc etc).

Comment: Ok, he quits immunity debugger. Then run the attack using the "JMP ESP" instruction address for WS2_32.DLL, as the new EIP address for the attack script : he runs the attack script, and echo server still alive, then on another shell he connects to the remote machine using nc 192.168.1.123 4444 (port 4444 for tcp bind shell), and payload gets executed, so he's connected on remote machine.

Comment: It works!!  Thanks !    Finally I noticed I could use any "jmp ebp" or "call ebp" instruction addresses for the exploit !   And sorry about that : My big mistake was to use a "staged" metasploit payload : "windows/shell/bind_tcp",  instead of "windows/shell_bind_tcp" !